# Fabric error: Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'git commit -m 'message'

Tags: python, git, fabric

I'm trying to setup a fabfile to deploy my Django app.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'git commit -m 'changed settings for prodserver'

```
$ fab create_branch_deploy_to_prodserver
[localhost] run: git checkout prodserver_server
[localhost] run: git merge master
[localhost] run: cp settings_prodserver.py settings.py
[localhost] run: git add settings.py
[localhost] run: git commit -m 'changed settings for prodserver'

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'git commit -m 'changed settings for prodserver''

Aborting.
```

Here if the Fabric function:

```
def create_branch_deploy_to_prodserver():  
    local("git checkout prodserver_server")  
    local("git merge master")  
    local('cp settings_prodserver.py settings.py') # 
    #local('git rm fabfile.py') #This is also creating error so it's commented out
    local('git add settings.py')  
    local("git commit -m 'changed settings for prodserver'")
```

Is it possible to make a git commit from Fabric?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to diagnose the issue when I added capture=False to the declaration:

```
local('git rm fabfile.py', capture=False)
local('git add settings.py', capture=False)
```

This allowed the error to be displayed more verbosely.

Apparently, the maintainer of Fabric will to revert `local`'s behavior back to not capturing by default, in 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a python-related issue like the one described in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/fab-user@nongnu.org/msg00853.html)?

> The main problem with this is that the `stdout`/`stderr` capturing is per-run/sudo invocation and not per-task.
>
> It would be wonderful if you could explain me how I could  collect *output*and *error* by only modifying the file called *`fabfile_runner.py`*.
>   Idealy the fabric task itself could be unmodified, this would allow to upload the the factory the same file that you have tested manually.
>
> Check out the Fabric source and look in the 'tests' folder, specifically tests/utils.py. It contains a single decorator, `@mock_streams`, which is capable of wrapping a function (any function in any Python code -- it's not Fabric specific, as I mentioned) and redirecting `sys.stdout` and/or `sys.stderr` for capture/examination.
>
> It's designed for use around functions, being a decorator, so you could use it directly by modifying your `fabfile_runner.py` like so:

*fabfile_runner.py*

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys
from test_fabfile import hello_world

def execute(task):
    output = StringIO()
    error = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = output
    sys.stderr = error
    task()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
    return (output.getvalue(), error.getvalue())

output, error = execute(hello_world)
print "output : %s" %output
print "error : %s" %error
```